# JSON API PHP finding depth

Tags: php, json, api

I need help with figuring out how to call some depth elements in API call. We're connecting API which company gave us and this is the code I have

```
<?php
    include("O3ON_API.php");                    
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $apiclient = O3ON_API_Connector::getInstance();
    $models = $apiclient->CallAPI('Model', 'sr-Latin-CS', '');
    $categories = $apiclient->CallAPI('Category', 'sr-Latin-CS', '');
?>
```

So when I want to call it, I do it this way

```
<?php 
    foreach($models as $model){
    echo '<div>'.$model->Name.'</div>';
    } 
?>
```

This all works well, but I am struggling on how to call field which has some depth. This is an example of their API

```
Model
   Name
   Image
        Category
        Price
```

So with the $model I can call first level which is Name and Image. But how can I call sub category Price or Category? I found some examples online, but since I got the documentation from company it's different then what I want to do.

I tried this but with no success

```
$model->Category->Name
$model->Category[0]
```

I am thankful to anyone who helps!

Comment: You can access `Category` only through `Image`. So `$model->Image->Category`. But without knowing the actual response, I am just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Use an if statement with `isset()` to check if the key exists first. Then nest foreach loops if necessary. print_r or json_encode followed by an immediate exit will shed some light on where you are in the process and how to adjust your code. You might also try is_array, count, `!empty` and similar approaches if you want to cover every possible edge case along the way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood. The `Category` is nested inside `Image` This should work:

```
$model->Image->Category
$model->Name
```

Check the structure with `var_dump()`